# javascript: question about constructor **new** keyword

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-5

from the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model:

> When JavaScript sees the new operator,
>   it creates a new generic object and
>   passes this new object as the value of
>   the this keyword to the WorkerBee
>   constructor function. The constructor
>   function explicitly sets the value of
>   the projects property, and implicitly
>   sets the value of the internal
>   **proto** property to the value of WorkerBee.prototype. (That property
>   name has two underscore characters at
>   the front and two at the end.) The
>   **proto** property determines the prototype chain used to return
>   property values. Once these properties
>   are set, JavaScript returns the new
>   object and the assignment statement
>   sets the variable mark to that object.

So basically if we have this function:

```
function Bee(first_name, second_name){
    this.FirstName=name;
    this.SecondName=name;
}
```

I want to know what is the difference between doing something like **var bee1 = new Bee("qwe", "asd");** vs:

```
var bee1={};
bee1.__proto__=Bee.prototype;
var r=Bee.call(bee1, "qwe", "asd");
if(r!==undefined){
    bee1=r;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one thing, `var bee1 = new Bee("qwe", "asd");` is cross-browser compatible.  Some browsers won't let you mess around with an object's `__proto__` field -- IE being one of those.

For another, it's less code, and makes more sense at first glance.

Also, in the second example, as of the first line, you've created `bee1` but haven't initialized it.  As of the second line, the system will consider it a `Bee`, but it's still not built like one.  If something goes awry in the constructor, or anywhere else between creation and construction, you can end up with a half-baked `Bee`.  This as opposed to `new Bee(...)`, which either gives you back a properly constructed `Bee` or throws an exception.